# EPS inside EPS as a link - any alternative to "run" command?

Tags: postscript, eps

Maybe this is a dumb question but I have zero experience in PostScript/EPS and I need to (try and) solve a problem I got (the functionality worked in the past...so I am told). All is under Windows 7 x64.

The requirement asks to Link an EPS file inside another EPS file. The way it was done was using the "run" command along with "translate" and "scale" in order to fit the child.eps into parent.eps. (this is done by a Java class)

Consider the following (simplified) example:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%!PS-Adobe EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 800 200

/Courier findfont 70 scalefont setfont
10 10 moveto
(Hello World!) show
%%EOF
```

The above works fine but if, before *%%EOF*, I add

> (child.eps) run

I get quite strange behaviors (tried this on 3 Windows PCs with exact same results):

- Adobe Illustrator CS5 (v15) works ok(ish)...it always works if Illustrator is **not open** and I **double-click** the file. But if I open Illustrator first then use its File -> Open dialog to
  open the EPS file, it fails with "unknown error"
- Adobe Illustrator CS6 fails to open the file with "unknown error" (all the time)
- GSView (with Ghostscript 9.07 and -dNOSAFER option) opens it correctly.

What am I missing? Or what am I doing wrong?

Is there any other way to link an EPS inside another EPS besides using the "run" command so I can get consistent results?

Thanks!

LE: both, Parent.eps and Child.eps are in the same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PostScript language doesn't have any concept of a 'link'. Not surprising when you consider that PostScript is a programming language.

Surprisingly, executing 'run' in an EPS file doesn't makes it an invalid EPS.

This is surprising to me because what you are *supposed* to do is *include* the subsidiary EPS file inside the parent. The whole point of an EPS file is that its a 'black box', to get it to work an encapsulating PostScript program merely needs to set up the CTM to scale the EPS into the space it wants, then execute the EPS. The EPS should not have any side effect.

Anyway, there is nothing else in PostScript which will do what you want. I strongly suspect that either Illustrator is shipping with no PostScript interpreter at all, or its restricted in some fashion for security reasons. Illustrator is not a reliable means for testing if PostScript is valid!

Why do you want to load it into Illustrator ? Have you considered using PDF instead of EPS ?

Comment: Hi Ken and thanks for fast reply.
Thing is that it is not my choice but it is the way the requirement came. EPS is accepted only. And the final user is using Illustrator CS5, hence I need to provide them a valid EPS file to be used inside Illustrator.

I was thinking my problem is related to some windows access rights. Or even Adobe's own implementation of how the files are accessed, since it (kinda) works in CS5 but not anymore in CS6.

Will try to dig in that direction. Thanks!

Comment: Your only likely solution, I expect, is to include the child EPS file in the parent one, in its entirety. That will 'probably' satisfy Illustrator's security concerns.

Comment: yes, unfortunately. Will have to search for a Java library that can do that. Thanks again for the help!
LE: don't know what happens but if I try to hit Enter to go on the second line, it just submits the answer :D Sorry for keep editing my answers.

Comment: Will accept the answer since it gave me enough information to know where to look from now.

Comment: Illustrator does support quite much of the postscript environment. But like most postscript devices the run time environment is a bit undefined, so illustrator does not allow you to access the local disk normally.

Comment: thanks joojaa! I came to the same conclusion after banging my head against the wall for a while :)